# How to read csv with separator inside json?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to read a csv file but the separator sometimes appear in the second column (json). Is it possible to escape pipe when it appears inside quotes ?

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = 'col1|{"a":"1","b":"2|3","c":"4"}'

df = pd.read_csv(
        StringIO(data),
        header=None,
        sep='|',      
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
        quotechar='"',
        doublequote=False
)
```

Current

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col1 | {"a":"1","b":"2 | 3","c":"4"} |

Expected

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | {"a":"1","b":"2|3","c":"4"} |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = """col1|'{"a":"1","b":"2|3","c":"4"}'"""
df = pd.read_csv(
        StringIO(data),
        header=None,
        sep='|',      
        quotechar="'"
)
```

pandas can recognize the value as a whole string if the value is enclosed in the specified `quotechar`, for that you need to surround the json like string in `''`.

Also I triple-quoted the `data` string to preserve the single quotes.
You can also write a simple file with the same string in a csv and try to read_csv with `quotechar = "'"`